# Ambiguous call between `vector<long long>` and `vector<string>` with initializer_list input

Tags: c++, ambiguous

Following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void fun(const std::vector<long long> &x) {
  std::cout << "long long" << std::endl;
}

void fun(const std::vector<std::string> &s) {
  std::cout << "string" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  fun({"a", "c"}); // ambiguous call.
}
```

can't compile due to ambiguous call. Why this happened? I didn't see any connection between `const char *` and `long long`.

I can write a new function to resolve ambiguity:

```
void fun(std::initializer_list<const char*> s)
{
    
}
```

But I still don't know what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector<std::string>` has a constructor that takes a `std::initializer_list<std::string>` as a parameter. This allows a `std::vector<std::string>` to be constructed from a `std::initializer_list<std::string>`.

However `"a"` and `"b"` are not `std::string`s, but string literals whose type is `const char [n]` (where `n` is a size of each literal string including the `'\0'` terminator); and when used in a `std::initializer_list` context they'll produce a `std::initializer_list<const char *>`.

Additionally C++ allows a maximum of one implicit conversion, but here two would be required: from `std::initializer_list<const char *>` to a `std::initializer_list<std::string>` (presuming that such an implicit conversion is even possible, it's not, so that's already a showstopper, but let's pretend there is one), and then from `std::initializer_list<std::string>` to a `std::vector<std::string>`, using a non-`explicit` constructor.

TLDR: the formal technical specification and rules for C++ run to more than thousand pages of text, and this is simply not allowed.

Comment: But why `vector<long long>` can be matched. If we write a function like this: ```void fun(long long x){};
fun("a");  //can't convert const char* to long long. ``` It can't match at all.